# can 'A plethora of' be used for anything?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> Plethora - a very large amount of something, especially a larger
>   amount than you need, want, or can deal with.

As per subject title, can **A plethora of ** be used for just anything?

For e.g.

- A plethora of tools / gadgets / instruments
- A plethora of letters / parcels
- A plethora of phone calls / emails / texts
- A plethora of complains
- A plethora of shoes / clothes / bags
- A plethora of packed lunch / lunch boxes / food / eggs
- A plethora of Gold / Coins / metal

....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Plethora" is something of an "educated" word, and so not something you should use lightly, without considering whether your audience [will understand what it means](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mTUmczVdik), or whether it sounds *pretentious* rather than *erudite*.

That being said, you can have a "plethora" of anything that makes sense.  Because "plethora" is synonymous with "overabundance", it would normally be of something  positive -- but the excess amount makes it an annoyance, hassle, or obstruction.  A "plethora" of *shoes*, or *coins*, or *texts* is fine if you would normally consider these to be good things in moderation, but a problem if you have too many.

In other words, "plethora" doesn't just mean "a lot".  It means "more than you can handle".  For example, I might say I have a "plethora" of job offers -- something that's usually good to have, but when I have too many it's hard for me to find the best one.

For this reason, something like a "plethora of *complaints*" is unusual.  In the right context the contrast can be humorous or satirical, but you have to explain it properly.  For example, I found this headline:

> [Congress approaches EC with plethora of complaints](https://www.business-standard.com/article/news-ians/congress-approaches-ec-with-plethora-of-complaints-119041601424_1.html).

My personal opinion is that this is awkward, as there seems to be no ironic context.  Here "plethora" simply implies "more complaints than the EC can handle".  I would prefer another word more often associated with a *negative* excess, such as *slew*:

> **[slew](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/slew)** (n): 3. A large number or quantity of something.  *Congress approaches EC with a **slew** of complaints*

Comment: I think "plethora" maybe *used to be* an "educated word", but it has been making its way down to us, the masses, and we pretty much use it like we use other words, and sometimes sarcastically. I don't think "a plethora of complaints" is awkward.

Comment: @LorelC.  It may be that it's become more common, or possibly that "the masses" have become better readers.  Ngram does show a marked increase in its use over the past 30 years.  But I'll concede that my dislike for "a plethora of complaints" is based on personal preference.